# Telegram Bot API InlineQueryResultAudio

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Okay i can send audio with some url in inline mode. But how can i send the local audio from the directory? Telegram Bot API return me this:

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned
>   HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
>   [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request:
>   CONTENT_URL_INVALID"}']

Comment: Guess you can't because telegram doesn't allow uploading files.
You could upload your audio on some dedicated service, like soundcloud, or any cloud, and then share the link via telegram.

Comment: Why doesn't allow? There is sendAudio method that allow upload and send audio via message

Answer (score 0):

`InlineQueryResultAudio` only accepts links while `InlineQueryResultCachedAudio` only accepts `file_id`. What you can do is post the files to your own server or upload it elsewhere to use the former one, or use `SendAudio` to get the file_id of it and use the latter one.